# htaccess how to redirect immediately to home.php?

Tags: .htaccess, indexing

I changed index.php to home.php with the following code "DirectoryIndex home.php".
Now I want that when people are visiting my website that it goes immediately to www.mywebsite.com/home.php instead of just www.mywebsite.com.

Is this possible?
I tried to Google it but I could not find what I was looking for.

I hope this explains my question.
My English isn't that good so I try my best to explain it as good as possible!

Comment: Why would you want to name index.php to home.php anyways, it's the root file and landingspage of every website and they are both SEO onfriendly so on that matter there's not much to improve tho.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add this rule to redirect `/index.php` to `/home.php`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /home.php [R=301,L]
```

Make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled

Answer (score 0):

Another option which would negate the redirect would be to set the `DirectoryIndex` directive. `DirectoryIndex home.php`

this would not cause a redirect when people visited your domain, however if they type index.php you'd still need the rewrite posted in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could create an `index.php` and put the following code in it:

```
<?php header("Location: /home.php"); ?>
```